# How to take screenshots with light filter enabled

Tags: colors

The background color of my website is #0062cc. When using flux (blue light filter software) this color gets darker. I want to use this new darker color as a background color.

I took several screenshots (pressing `PrtSc`), but they all ignored the blue filter, so I can't know which color corresponds to the darker color.

How to take a screenshot and get the same colors that I see when `flux`  is turned on ?